# Adding parent to child document

Tags: sql, delphi, recursion, firebird

I am using a database with two tables:

```
HEADING:(ID, CAPTION, CUSTOMER_ID,DATE, TDOC, ID_PAR) --  ID is PK
                                                      --  ID_PAR is FK Related 
                                                          to HEADING.ID    

LINES   : (ID, NDOC,QTE)                              --  ID is PK NDOC is FK RELATED TO 
                                                          HEADING.ID
```

`HEADING` has a recursive query to get all childs of a `HEADING ID`
for example an invoice with many delivery notes.

In that system the lines of an invoice are not typed  we type only  delivery notes

How to get all the lines of an invoice in case of the datasets are related as master-detail?

---

Heading dataset

ID PARENT_ID  DOC_DATE  DOC_TYPE

01 NULL                  A    
02 01                    B    
03 02                    C    
04 02                    C

Lines Dataset

ID_PK     NDOC_FK   CODE_PROD  QTE

### Heading

01        03         P1         5
02        03         P10        20
03        03         P67        65
04        04         P61        34

SQL LINES RESULT  for heading.ID=01

PRODUCT QTE

P1      5
  P10     20
  P67     65
  P61     61

Comment: Sample data from each of the tables would help, but there's no recursion necessary if I'm understanding you correctly. This is a simple `SELECT` from the `Lines` table that relates it to the `Heading` table where `Lines.NDOC = Heading.ID`.

Comment: something like `select * from lines where ndoc = 123456` - ABC of SQL

Comment: In case of an invoice its lines are lines of  many delivery notes ? so

Comment: Invoice.ID only  exists in heading dataset.

Comment: show the sample data, the sample output and explanation why it should be exactly this output from the given sample data and not anything else. As of now it seems no one can deduce what picture you have in your mind.

Comment: The sample data you added suggests that "How to get all the lines of an invoice" was wrong question and what you actually wants is "getting all the lines" of some parent invoice *and of many other invoices* that are direct or indirect children of it. If so then what is the "HEADING has a recursive query to get all childs of a HEADING ID" you mention? Probably you can ustilise that query like this" `WITH ( recursive-query-to-get-all-children-including-root ) as X /*do*/ Select * from lines where ndoc = X.id`. Of course if I guessed what you actually wanted, from the sample data.

Comment: Another option to think about is to re-make Heading table and get read of `ID` and `PARENT_ID` columns, instead of which using **nested numeric sets**. Instead of `ID` make two columns `LEFT_BOUND` and `RIGHT_BOUND`. Then parent document for example will have `100; 300` bounds and its children would have for example `150; 200` and `250; 299` bounds. Then for the lines query you would only have to specify parent's bounds and all the children are automatically included. This approach works well when data is rarely changed and frequently hierarchically read.